# What was the nature of the visible part of the viscous wake trailing the Apollo CM during reentry?

Tags: apollo-program, reentry, plasma

This diagram suggests a helix in the wake, was it a single-helix, a multiple helix, or a superhelix?  Is there any other part of the wake that would be visible?
[image]

Comment: The parts of the wake that are visible depends on its temperature.
 See https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12759/11260 for more info